# How large a study would you need to deal with the 10X programmer?

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power

The theory of the 10X programmer states that there is a range of 10X between the fastest and slowest programmer with a given amount of experience. Or in other words, if the fastest programmer takes 10 minutes, the slowest programmer in the group takes 100 minutes to perform the same task.

I have two groups, lets say group A uses Test Driven Development and group B, the control group, doesn't.

I find that on average group A is 30% faster than group B, with the usual 10X range in both groups. How many people do I need in each group for this finding to be statistically meaningful?

Comment: How are the programmers distributed within each group, in terms of ability? Are those in group B, say, uniformly distributed in $[b, 10b]$ and those in group B also uniformly distributed in $[0.7b, 7b]$, so that the 30% differential you mention is actually the true underlying value?

Comment: What you aim at doing is *sample size calculation*. For this, you typically need to specify three ingredients: the true effect size (this may be your 30%), the significance level $\alpha$ (typically $\alpha=0.05$) and the [statistical power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power) $\beta$ you aim for (typically $\beta=0.8$). Standard sample size calculators will assume that your test statistics are normally distributed, which usually works, but not always - which is why I asked about the raw data distributions in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

We need to make some reasonable assumptions to get an impression of the numbers: Uniformely distributed programmers are one and we compute with the 10 to 100 example in the slower group.

Standard deviation of a large group of programmers uniformely in between 10 and 100 minutes mixed with one 1.0-30%=0.7 times this time:

`sd(c(runif(1e6, 10, 100), .7*runif(1e6,10,100)))`
is roughly 24. For the effect size, we need the difference in means.
`55 - .7*55 = .3*55 = 16.5`

```
library(pwr)
power.t.test(d = 16.5/55, power=.9)
```

results in

```
Two-sample t test power calculation 

n = 234.4628
delta = 0.3
sd = 1
sig.level = 0.05
power = 0.9
alternative = two.sided

NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```

Of course, some people do all the work for a power of just 80%. Of course, if we assume normally distributed programmers, we might find a smaller standard deviation. For all practical purposes, you'll have to make some assumptions which are plausible but not shure. Therefore power calculation in the real world often gives but a hint towards the appropriate numbers.

Comment: Forgive me, this is all above my head. So keeping with your assumptions are correct, 243 people per group would give a 90% chance that the 30% improvement is real and not just coincidence?

Comment: No. If there truely is an effect size of $\delta = 0.3$ and you perform a study of any given size, there is a certain chance, that you will find a significant difference in your sample ($p < .05$) and a chance, that you do not find it ($p > 0.05$) even though it was there. If you want to have a 90% chance of finding an effect of size $\delta=0.3$ (in a two-sided test) you'll need a sample of given size.  If you can live with a smaller chance or a one-sided test, this number will decrease rapidly.

Comment: (ctd) I advise, that you concern yourself with the concept of effect sizes (in this case 'Cohen's d') and the concept of one-tailed and two-tailed testing an download a program called `G*power` to play with the numbers (or the program `R` and the additional package `pwr`which I used in my answer above).